# Azure list running servers

Tags: azure, powershell

I've been trying to get a list of running VM's but so far I can get the status but I only want the running ones. I need a little help with filting based on powerstate = running

```
$groups = (Get-AzResourceGroup).ResourceGroupName
foreach($group in $groups)

{
(get-azvm -ResourceGroupName $group -Status | select Name,Powerstate)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much there, you just need to use `where` to filter out the PowerState:

```
$groups = (Get-AzResourceGroup).ResourceGroupName
foreach($group in $groups)
{
    (get-azvm -ResourceGroupName $group -Status | select Name,Powerstate | Where { $_.PowerState -eq "VM Running" })
}
```

Note that the PowerState is **VM Running** not just **Running**.